# printing contents in a new tab prints a blank page

Tags: javascript, html, printing, new-window

I am trying to print the contents of a div to a new tab, however, it print a blank page only for the first time. When i manually print the page, it works fine. I am loading 2 tables wrapped in a div.

HTML structure:

```
<div class="receipt_bg" id="print_receipt">
  <div id="div1">
    table1
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    table2
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="print_btn">Print</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#print_btn').click(printClick);

function printClick(receipt_bg) {
  var DocumentContainer = $('.receipt_bg').html();
  var WindowObject = window.open("PrintWindow","_blank");
  WindowObject.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'+ '<html><head><title>test print receipt</title>    <link href="../css/style.defaultprint.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><body>' +     DocumentContainer + '</body></html>')
  setTimeout(WindowObject.print(), 5);
  WindowObject.close();
}
```

I even tried using
    WindowObject.onload = WindowObject.print();
instead of
    setTimeout(WindowObject.print(), 5);
still it doesn't seem to work. I saw a similar post, but its solutions did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this url.
It contain few example for printing content from page.It has all you need.

I had use jQuery Print Element 1.2 for print, in this, if you have large content to print then you need to increases time out from 50 to 500,other wise it will show blank page as you face issue, but for me it is only happend in Chrome browser, other then that i haven't face this issue. 
check printElement js. below url contain nice example with demo and source.

Check this : [jQuery Print Page Options](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-print-page-options/)

Here is the code , which will help you.

```
function printClick(receipt_bg) {
    var DocumentContainer = $('.receipt_bg').html();
    var WindowObject = window.open("", "printElementWindow", "width=650,height=440,scrollbars=yes");
    WindowObject.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'+ '<html><head><title>test print receipt</title>    <link href="../css/style.defaultprint.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><body>' +     DocumentContainer + '</body><script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(printPage(),1000);  function printPage(){focus();print();}<\/script></html>')
    WindowObject.close();
 }
```

This will work for you, here i added one javascript function to your window code, which will executed after timeout. try it, and let me know , is it work for you or not. you can extend or decrees timeout as per your content.

Comment: Can i not get it right without using any plugin for this? I tried increasing the time out from 50 to 500 and even 1000, still no luck.

Comment: @ekta : Did you got your answer or i help you further ?

Comment: I am able to get this right by using some plugin, but i dont want to do that. Can you please help me in this without using a plugin? I tried increasing the time as well inside setTimeout().

Comment: @ekta check updated answer, it has your solution. try example i mention in that.